# Pass object to function in html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm trying to pass an object on a button click, but it doesn't pass the object properly. How can I fix this?

```
function addEventToCart(event) {
    $("#mentorItems").append(
        `<div id="${event.id}" class="alert alert-dismissible">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick=removeEvent(event)>&times;</button>
        </div>`);
```

The removeEvent function looks something like this:

```
function removeEvent(event) {
     var color = event.color;
 }
```

All the properties in event are undefined, so I assume something is going wrong in the passing? I've tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246831/javascript-pass-object-to-a-javascript-created-from-string) solution but no success either.

Comment: event is a dangerous one to call it, there is something like a window.event that will be there as well. Do you have to pass it through html, if yes, use the `id` and find your `event` in javascript later, if not attach an event handler, which is a much cleaner way, or add the data through your data attributes and get the current target element from the event handler that is sent along

Comment: Is renaming it to evt fine? I mainly called it because I'm working with FullCalendar but I'll keep your comment in mind! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event` is undefined object because you can't pass an object as plain text (you did it when you wrote `removeEvent(event)`
I would try changing the structure:

```
function addEventToCart(evt) {
    var $div = $('<div id="' + evt.id + '" class="alert alert-dismissable"></div>');
    var $btn = $('<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>');
    $btn.on('click', function() {
        var color = evt.color;
        alert(color);
    });
    $div.append($btn);
    $('#mentorItems').append($div);
}
```

Comment: Though your way is a cleaner approach than the OPs, you could think of helping the OP understand why you offer this change, and what it brings, potentially what other ways are available and their pro and cons, code only answers could create more questions ;)

Comment: I have a bunch of code running in the function being called .. I'd very much prefer it in a separate function.. is that not possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Change the inline code of the 'onclick' section to this:
`removeEvent(evt);`

Comment: like this? $btn.on('click', removeEvent(evt)); My code doesn't seem to hit the function when I'm click the button..

Comment: No. Like this:
`$btn.on('click', function() {
    removeEvent(evt);
});`
@Icepickle I just added a short explanation of what I did :)

Comment: You are very welcome @J.Kirk. I've also added a short explanation for the reason I changed your code structure, so you may understand why I did it :)